# Proof of set being a sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, dual-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

Suppose $K$ is a compact metric space and let $F$ be a continuous linear functional on $C(K)$ (here $C(K)$ denotes the set of continuous functions on $K$). One version of the Riesz representation theorem (see e.g theorem 7.3 of https://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf) states that there exists a unique finite signed Borel measure $\mu$ such that $F(f) = \int f d\mu$ for all $f \in C(K)$.

Under the assumption that $F(f) \geq 0$ for every positive $f \in C(K)$, I want to prove that the set $A =\{E \in \mathcal{B}: \mu(E) \geq 0\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

The fact that $K \in A$ follows from $\mu(K) = F(\chi_K) \geq 0$ since $\chi_K \geq 0$ is continuous. However, I am stuck at proving that $A$ is closed under countable unions and complements.

Do you have any suggestions on how one could proceed?

Comment: If $F(f) \geq 0$ for every positive $f$ then $\mu$ is a positive measure. See Rudin's RCA for a proof.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do you mind pointing me to the section where it is proven? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Rudin actually proves Riesz Representation Theorem for positive linear functionals first and then goes to continuous linear functionals. You just have to look at the first theorem in the section 'The Riesz Representation Theorem'.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, then $A$ equals the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$.

Because $K$ is compact,
each element in $C(K)$ has a compact (and therefore bounded) image
and thus is a bounded function.
So $C(K)$ equals $C_b(K)$,
the space of continuous bounded functions on $K$,
and $F$ is a continuous linear functional on $C_b(K)$.
By your assumption $F$ is also positive.
So you can apply Theorem 7.4 in https://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf
which tells you that the measure $\mu$ is positive,
i.e., $\mu(E)\geq 0$ for each $E$ in $\mathcal{B}$.
So $A$ equals $\mathcal{B}$.